BIN_TO_UUID and UUID_TO_BIN does not exist in mySQL
I am using XAMPP and Nodejs with mysql2 to make a connection to a database, however, in both mysql and nodejs query, when using BIN_TO_UUID() or UUID_TO_BIN():
static async getAll({ genre }) {
    const result = await connection.query(
       "SELECT title, year, director, duration, poster, rate, BIN_TO_UUID(id) id FROM movie;"
    )

    console.log(result)
}

In this case I get the following error:
code: 'ER_SP_DOES_NOT_EXIST', errno: 1305, sql: 'SELECT title, year, director, duration, poster, rate, BIN_TO_UUID(id) id FROM movie;', sqlState: '42000', sqlMessage: 'FUNCTION moviesdb.BIN_TO_UUID does not exist'
And in mySQL, when I try this line of code:
CREATE TABLE movie (
    id BINARY(16) PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT (UUID_TO_BIN(UUID())),
    title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    year INT NOT NULL,
    director VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    duration INT NOT NULL,
    poster TEXT,
    rate DECIMAL(2,1) NOT NULL
);

I get this error:
#1901 - The function or expression 'UUID_TO_BIN()' cannot be used in the DEFAULT of id
Is there any alternative I can use in this case or any way to implement UUID_TO_BIN AND BIN_TO_UUID?

Notice that UUID_TO_BIN(), BIN_TO_UUID(), and IS_UUID() functions are only available in MySQL 8.0 or later.  (https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-basics/mysql-uuid/)

So upgrade to a more recent version of MySQL.

Polyfill for BIN_TO_UUID and UUID_TO_BIN

XAMPP has been using maruadb instead of mysql, so check out which version of mariadb implements these functions first.

UUID data type was added in MariaDB 10.7

What does select version(); say

@ysth says that the version is: "10.4.32-MariaDB
"

10.4 is past end of life and no longer receiving security updates; consider it insecure and upgrade as soon as possible.  upgrade to a long term support release (11.4 or 10.11 or 10.6).  note that mariadb and mysql are separate products, with different features; mariadb does not have the bin/uuid functions, though 11.4 or 10.11 have a uuid data type that you may want to use

https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-15854
